# Close a java modal JDialog from within the owner class (a JFrame)

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jdialog

i am feeling a bit bad about this question because i think this is probably not the
way a JDialog should be used but anyway:

I have a very simple JDialog that just contains a label and i want to show it
in situations where the application is running a task that just runs for a few
seconds on the main swing thread. The dialog has to be model to make sure that 
the user cannot click anything on the main GUI while the short blocking task is
executed. When the task is done, the modal dialog should be disposed of without
any user interaction... and this does not seem to work with a modal dialog since
once it's setVisible(true) method is called, execution seems to stop and i can't
figure out how to close it from the owner side without user interaction...

I would be very grateful for help or suggestions on how to implement such a blocking
dialog in a different way.

Comment: Why don't you use SwingX' `BusyLabel` or `BusyPainter` instead? You could just put the label or a component with the painter onto the classpane and remove it when the operation is finished. Or yet better, use `JXFrame` which provides a `setWaitPaneVisible(...)` method.

Comment: If somehow you can take this task to your `JDialog` related class and call it from their after setting it to `visible(true)`, might  be it can work, though it's tough to say without any POSTED CODE part :(

Comment: thanks for hinting me to SwingX - i am currently having a look at the BusyLabel API which looks like i could use it for my purposes - and sorry for not posting example code - i hoped to have described the general problem well enough to make clear what i tried to do

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your execution will stop if you show a modal dialog on the UI thread. To overcome this, you can use a SwingWorker or even just create a new Thread